# Adding to multiprocessing.Queue from a generator

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a very large list of jobs that I want to add to Queue, and start having workers process.

Right now I have something like

```
Q = multiprocessing.Queue()

for chunk in generator_of_a_lot_of_data :
   Q.put(chunk)

... do something with the jobs in the queue ...
```

With this code, all the data has to get into the queue before I can start working on it. How can I add items to the queue, from a generator, in a non-blocking way?

Comment: Start the workers before putting jobs to the queue?

Comment: Awesome, that's just the little direction I needed.